# Alignment text of actionbar tab?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-actionbar

I try to customize actionbar tabs. Look on the picture:

[image]

My code:

```
   <style name="ActionBarTabBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:showDividers">end</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/actionbar_tab_divider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionBarTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
        <item name="android:measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@style/ListView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTab</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBar</item>
    </style>
```

I would like to align the text of tabs to center. When I try to set up showDividers to value `middle`, divider is not visible. It is visible with values `beggining` or `end`.

Answer (score 4):

After more attempts, I've got desired result.

This is my code, that works properly.

```
<style name="ActionBarTabBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">30dp</item>
</style>


<style name="ActionBarTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/actionbar_tab_divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBar</item>
</style>
```

It was needed to specify the style for Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView and for this item set up the divider.

Answer (score 2):

Delete styles you don't need to override in order to style your tabs like you described:

```
<style name="ActionBarTabBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/actionbar_tab_divider</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>        
</style>
```

Comment: But I want to use custom divider. Your code is only for background.

Comment: Ok I edited it. You don't need to specify deviderpadding etc.